# Using for auto in nested loops

Tags: c++, nested-loops, c++20, mongo-cxx-driver

Good day, I have been recently trying to move to c++ in order to accelerate some of my apps. It's probably due to lack in my background that I am making such a stupid mistake, however, I am getting `interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV` while trying to run it with the nested loops:

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find({});
for(auto doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << "TEST FIRST" << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
    for (auto doc2 : cursor) {
        std::cout << "FIRST: " << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
        std::cout << "SECOND: " << bsoncxx::to_json(doc2) << "\n";
    } }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: the code you posted is missing a `"`. It cannot compile, it is not the code that cuases a SIGSEGV. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know much about `mongocxx` but it looks like you could use `const&` instead of copying: `for(auto const& doc : cursor)` and `for (auto const& doc2 : cursor)` - wait a second - you loop over the same `cursor`? That's probably the problem. Shouldn't the inner loop be over `doc`? `for (auto const& doc2 : doc)`

Comment: Are you getting the `SIGSEGV` in the first or the second cout?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've edited, though it's just a typo here in the code example. The compiler would give me a different error if I forgot to add ". In any case, thx for you attention

Comment: @Ventu it works absolutely fine when there's one loop, so I guess yes it falls somewhere within the inner loop. Surprisingly I even get some output before `SIGSEGV`

Comment: It probably doesn't like two nested iterations on the same cursor. Try two cursor instances.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm trying to compare each element of a collection type against each element of a collection type. And yes `const&` made wonders for me. If you add that as a reply with just a tiny bit of explanation why `const&` is so essential. I will be very glad to accept that as an answer. Many-many thx, I actually work with the COVID-19 data and probably your contribution today's made the world a bit better.

Comment: @Anna-Lischen I wish I knew more about `mongcxx` to provide a proper answer. My suggestion regarding using a reference (`&`) with `auto` is that you then will reference the object that the `cursor` iterator points at instead of _copying_ that object (which is what `auto` without `&` will do). Interesting note about the `cursor::begin()`: "_If `begin()` is called more than once, the `cursor::iterator` returned points to the next remaining result, not the result of the original call to `begin()`._"

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are iterating over `cursor` in both loops, but from the `mongocxx` doc:

> [...] Dereferencing any non-end() iterator always gives the first remaining document in the cursor. Incrementing one non-end iterator is equivalent to incrementing them all.

And

> [...] If begin() is called more than once, the cursor::iterator returned points to the next remaining result, not the result of the original call to begin().

In C++, range-loop are just a hidden way of using iterators, the problem is that (according to the quote above), when you increment the inner-loop iterator, you're actually incrementing the outer-loop one. Your code is (approximately) equivalent to:

```cpp
for (auto it = cursor.begin(); it != cursor.end(); ++it) {
    // there may or may not be a ++it here, that does not change the explanation
    // but the documentation of mongocxx is unclear on this
    for (++it; it != cursor.end(); ++it) { }
}
```

The issue is that when the inner-loop reaches `cursor.end()`, you increment `it` in the outer-loop, and you then compare it to `cursor.end()` again, which is probably why you get your `SIGSEV`.

The only way to do what you want would be to either have two cursors, or store everything in a container (e.g., a `std::vector`), and then iterates over the vector (you will not have the same issue with `std::vector`).

---

Side-note regarding the `const&` mentioned in the comment — When you do `for(auto doc: cursor)`, this is equivalent (not exactly, but you'll get the idea) to:

```cpp
for (auto it = cursor.begin(); it != cursor.end(); ++i) {
    auto doc = *it; // here, you make a copy of *it, this is expensive
}
```

Replacing `auto` by `const auto&` change the declaration of `doc` and makes it a reference to the value pointed by the iterator.

Aside from the other issues I mentioned above, this will give you improper results since when you iterate in the inner-loop, you're actually also incrementing the outer-loop iterator, so the outer-loop `doc` reference will either point to something that's not there anymore (UB) or point to the new iterator's underlying object, which is actually `doc2`, so you will have `&doc == &doc2`, i.e., both `doc` and `doc2` will point to the same object (with both `const auto&`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're probably right.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually I'm not sure... Looking at the source code, calling `begin()` when iteration has already started basically does nothing so the `cursor` state is unchanged (and the `iterator` actually uses the underlying `cursor`). I will mark it as "I don't know" in the answer since that does not change the explanation anyway.

Comment: Ok, the code is facit. I was just reading "_if `begin()` is called more than once, the `cursor::iterator` returned points to the next remaining result, not the result of the original call to `begin()`_" and made my assumption from that.